# How to check object has any property in knockout js

Tags: javascript, object, knockout.js

How to check whether an observable object has a property exist in knockout js.
I have tried with `hasOwnProperty` and it always return false to me.

My code is as follows:

```html
    <div data-bind="click:setObject">Click here</div>
    <div data-bind="click:init">check console</div>
    <script>
        var ViewModel = function() {
            var self = this;
            this.arrayVal = ko.observable({});
            this.setObject = function(){  /* i have set property here  */
                self.arrayVal({
                    id:10
                });
            };
            self.init = function(){
                console.log(self.arrayVal());
                console.log(self.arrayVal.hasOwnProperty('id'));  /* on second click (after setObject ) i expect trut,but it returned false */
            }
            self.init();
        };
        ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel()); 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to obtain the value inside the `arrayVal` observable:

```
console.log(self.arrayVal().hasOwnProperty('id'));
```

The observable itself has the method `hasOwnProperty` but not the property `id`, therefore

```
self.arrayVal.hasOwnProperty('id');    // false, 'id' doesn't exist on the observable
```

while

```
self.arrayVal().hasOwnProperty('id');    // true, 'id' exists on the observable's value
```

Comment: Rather the observable _does_ have the `hasOwnProperty` method, but it _doesn't_ have an `id` property, hence it returning false.

Comment: Very true, I was perhaps tripping over myself to post the answer ASAP. I've edited the answer to reflect this. Thanks.

Comment: No need to rush on SO - the best answers should float to the top - saw a Q yesterday where the 5th or 6th answer posted (about 7 or 8 minutes after the first) was the most correct and get plenty of votes :)